# Convert from haml to erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, erb

I try to convert the code from haml to erb but I'm getting stuck and don't know why.

Here is the original code I want to convert: https://github.com/gmarik/simple-backend-example/blob/master/app/views/backend/resource/_index.html.haml

And here is what I have right now. Can someone take a look at it and give me some hints. Thanks.

I doubt this line the most: 
`%tr[resource]{odd_or_even}`

I think that it might be like:
`<tr> <% @resource{odd_or_even} %>`

RubyMine gave me an error at this line:
`<%= paginate collection %>`

```
    <% content_for(:header) do %>
      <h1><%= resource_class.model_name.human(count: 2) %></h1>

    <ul class="tabs">
       <li class="active"><%= link_to "Index", "#" %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "New", new_resource_path %> </li>
    </ul>
    <table class='zebra-striped'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <% attributes.each do |attr| %>
            <th> <%= resource_class.human_attribute_name(attr) %></th>
          <th> &nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% collection.each do |resource| %>
          <tr> <% @resource{odd_or_even} %>
            <% attributes.each do |attr| %>

            <td> <%= resource.public_send(attr).to_s.truncate(20) %> </td>        
            <td class='row-actions'>
              <%= link_to 'show', resource_path(resource) %>
              |
              <%= link_to 'edit', edit_resource_path(resource) %>
              |
              <%= link_to 'destroy', resource_path(resource), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?" %>
            </td>
        <% end %> 
      </tbody> 
    </table>  
    <%= paginate collection %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation here : http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#object_reference_

I'd say it's :

```
<tr id="<%= "#{resource.class.name.underscore}_#{resource.to_key}" %>" class="<%= resource.class.name.underscore %>">
```

This is to translate `%tr[resource]`.

Now, the `{odd_or_even}` will just convert the result hash of the helper `odd_or_even` to map them as attributes on the `tr`.

If we take a look at the definition of the method here : https://github.com/gmarik/simple-backend-example/blob/master/app/helpers/backend/application_helper.rb

We see it's just a call to [`cycle`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle) in order to set an extra class. Therefore we end up with:

```
<tr id="<%= "#{resource.class.name.underscore}_#{resource.to_key}" %>" class="<%= "#{resource.class.name.underscore} #{cycle("odd", "even", name: "rows")}" %>">
```

Now, all of this won't fix the problem of `paginate`. Add the error message if you're still stuck on this.

Comment: Ok well, let's delete all these comments :p

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think that <%= paginate collection %> will not affect much if I remove it so I have done that. It still show error "[RUBY] Expected: end" although I don't know where I have problem. Here is the current code: http://pastebin.com/sAuXy2F0

Comment: You're not closing `<% content_for(:header) do %>`. Add `<% end %>` at the very end of your file